# Application of Fourier Series in Circuit

Tags: dc, fourier, harmonics

I am trying to find \$v_o(t)\$ in the circuit below, where
$$v_s(t) = 3 - \frac{6}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin2\pi n t$$
The correct answer is $$v_o(t) = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi n t - \tan^{-1}4n\pi)}{n\sqrt{1 + 16n^2\pi^2}}$$
but I got
$$v_o(t) = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{6}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi n t - \tan^{-1}4n\pi)}{n\sqrt{1 + 16n^2\pi^2}}$$

What is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Please reformat your formulas. The question is unreadable.

Comment: can you include your working. A factor of two came from somewhere *IF* what you think is the answer is correct.

Comment: Excellent edit, @Null!! That's a great example of how it's done.

Comment: @JonRB Quick question: What would be the phasor form of the summation part of vs(t)? Is it \frac{6}{n\Pi}\angle 180

Comment: How can there be a change in the DC component (from 3 to 3/2)? The output should look like an open circuit at DC.